# System.Data.Entity.DbContext can't find to add as a reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I go to build my project, I get this error:

> The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I am trying to access my `DbContext` that I created with EF5.
I tried to add `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` to my references, but I couldn't find it. What should I do?

Comment: Try by adding the entity framework assembly reference through NuGet.

Comment: what exactly i should search ?

Comment: 1) Read http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget  2) Search for "entity framework" from NuGet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Select the project which throws this error
2. Go to the menu View -> Other windows -> Package Manager Console
3. Make sure your problematic project got selected in the default
   Project" drop-down in the PMC console.
4. then type the command "install-package entityframework -version
   5.0.0.0"

It should install the missing version.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the Solution Explorer
2. Right-Click on References -> Manage NuGet Packages...
3. Select Online-> Microsoft and .NET Click
4. Click Install next to .Net EntityFramework